# What tools are needed to code a website in Japanese

Tags: html, localization, internationalization

How do I code a website in Japanese and Chinese.

I have the HTML and graphics
I want to change the text to Japanese and Chinese symbols

1. what tools can be used to auto convert
2. what tools can be used to correct the auto converted text
3. what is necessary to serve it online

Comment: Can you define more clearly what you mean by conversion? Do you mean automatic translation services like Google Translate?

Comment: If you're talking about serving japanese/chinese content, the magic word is using UTF-8 as the encoding for your web site: This will solve most of your problems. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833940/multilingual-site-english-japanese-korean-languages

Comment: please put here an example of the input you have and the out put you want.

Comment: These "symbols" are actually ideographic characters.

Comment: I want some in china or japan to read my site in chinese or japanese.  So i need to have the content show chinese/japanese characters characters

Comment: I want to type english and have japanese stored in a document and read by some one in japan

Comment: @user I don't understand. You want to automatically translate typed content? Automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other website. Just make sure you use an character set that can represent the chinese and/or japanese characters. But with anything Unicode-based like UTF-8 you should be fine. Also the web-server needs to specify the character set with the Content-Type header.

If you don’t know any chinese/Japanese though you better find someone to translate the text for you. Shouldn’t be too hard to find and hire a translator.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad will do the trick, provided you have source text written in Unicode. If you're looking for something better try Notepad++. Both will "autoconvert", meaning given UTF-16 BE/LE, you will be able to save web page in UTF-8. Notepad++ should be able to convert from Shift-JIS (CP932) to UTF-8 as well.

You didn't mention OS, so I am assuming Windows. Well, you won't have to correct anything if you are transcoding from standard Windows code page to UTF-8 (this is done via system call to NLS API).

You don't need anything fancy to serve CJK (Chinese / Japanese / Korean) web pages, simply use any standard web server. You may even view it from your disk, it should work as well.

Remember to set proper encoding in a meta element of headers (<head>) section.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic translation services are horrible, especially so for Western to Asian languages. Trust me - I'm a native Chinese speaker, and I usually read Google Translated websites for laughs. They are good *enough* if you're not a speaker of the language and need to understand the gist of the content, but if you're serious about attracting international visitors you should consider getting a professional translator.

If you only need this for the occasional international visitor, you could add in a small translate bar/box on the client side with services like Bing/Google Translate. See instructions for setting them up here:

Bing: http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget/
Google: http://translate.google.com/translate_tools

These would be much easier than setting up your own translator on the server side, and far more flexible too. They can't do anything about the graphics, but for the brilliant price of free, I think they are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest bet, without any additional setup is to use the proxy service Transposh offers http://blog.transposh.com/2013/07/finally-proxy-is-ready-for-alpha-testing.html